# What kinds of mint are these?

Tags: identification, houseplants, mint

I bought two mint plants in different places; I bought them as supposedly being peppermint and spearmint but they don't really look like I'd expect, although the flavors ARE sort of in line with what you'd expect for peppermint and spearmint.

[image: Not quite peppermint, I think]
[image: Not quite peppermint close-up]

[image: Not sure this is spearmint either?]
[image: Supposedly spearmeint close-up]

P.S. there's some old leaves in there but the white spots are sunscreen.

Comment: I am not sure this question can be answered as mint hybridizes so easily

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @kevinskio I'm not expecting to get them genome sequenced, so to say... but perhaps a bit of a more precise guess. The first one with lots or growth is supposed to be peppermint, and the other one wlth just the one stem is supposedly spearmint

Comment: Exactly opposite what I'd expect based on **my** peppermint and spearmint plants, but yeah, mints are bit hard to nail down (or, "what it smells like is what it is") as there are really multiple thousands of variants.

Comment: There is not just one, easily identified thing, called "spearmint". Likewise for "peppermint". Published guides and books and other literature to the contrary.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Pretty much why I posted this in the first place hahaha.

Comment: So... after doing a bit more digging, it seems the second one should be Mentha *citrata*, AKA?Eau de cologne mint or orange mint.